# Reading XML template, make a change and display on page

Tags: c#, xml

Hi I have a preformatted xml template file that lists all country codes.

I need to load this into a C# scipt and loop through and match the mc_name attribute to a country code and add a value attribute to the node.

I then need to render the edited xml on the page so it can be used as a data source for a flash chart.

example of xml is:

```
<areas>
  <area title="AFGHANISTAN" mc_name="AF"></area>
  <area title="ALAND ISLANDS" mc_name="AX"></area>
  <area title="ALBANIA" mc_name="AL"></area>
  <area title="ALGERIA" mc_name="DZ"></area>
  <area title="ANDORRA" mc_name="AD"></area>
  <area title="ANGOLA" mc_name="AO"></area>
  <area title="ANGUILLA" mc_name="AI"></area>
  <area title="ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA" mc_name="AG"></area>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can process the XML:

```
var xml = @"<areas> 
  <area title=""AFGHANISTAN"" mc_name=""AF""></area> 
  <area title=""ALAND ISLANDS"" mc_name=""AX""></area> 
  <area title=""ALBANIA"" mc_name=""AL""></area> 
  <area title=""ALGERIA"" mc_name=""DZ""></area> 
  <area title=""ANDORRA"" mc_name=""AD""></area> 
  <area title=""ANGOLA"" mc_name=""AO""></area> 
  <area title=""ANGUILLA"" mc_name=""AI""></area> 
  <area title=""ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA"" mc_name=""AG""></area> 
</areas>
";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("areas/area");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    // You can view existing attribute values through node.Attributes.
    var att = doc.CreateAttribute("value");
    att.Value = "something";
    node.Attributes.Append(att);
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```