# How to read an XML template from C#?

Tags: c#, xml, templates

I have created an xml template for a report and basically i need to create a not very complicated program that creates a report with the information given by the user. Any help would be really really really appreciated. I really need some!

Links anything would be a help. Im so puzzled

Thank you

Comment: looks quite similar [Reading XML template, make a change and display on page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349961/reading-xml-template-make-a-change-and-display-on-page)

Comment: Are you simply asking how to use XML from a C# program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) or [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx). The XmlDocument is the easiest to query.